# Get FixedDocuments out of a FixedDocumentSequence

Tags: c#, .net, xps

Fairly simple:

I have an XPSDocument that I am pulling off of disk. I would like to get the FixedDocuments out of this XpsDocument, but I've hit a bit of a cropper since I can only get a FixedDocumentSequence, and I can't work out how to pull the XpsDocuments from this sequence.

So far I've tried something like:

```
FixedDocument doc = (FixedDocument)myFixedDocSequence.References.First();
```

That cast doesn't work, but it illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`myFixedDocSequence.References.First();` should return a `DocumentReference`. From that instead of casting have you tried using the [`DocumentReference.GetDocument` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.documentreference.getdocument%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which returns a `FixedDocument`? The code would look like this:

```
DocumentReference docReference = myFixedDocSequence.References.First();
FixedDocument doc = docReference.GetDocument(false);
```

Read the documentation linked to above for more information on the `GetDocument` parameter options. Also unless you're sure `References.First()` won't be null, consider using `FirstOrDefault()` and checking for null before using the returned object.

Comment: Cheers. I had a bit of trouble finding documentation on anything late in the day, but that might be because my head was full of fog :)

And don't worry, I do normally use FirstOrDefault() :)