# Extract a single page from an XPS document

Tags: c#, .net, xps, xps-generation

I need to split an existing XPS Document and create a new XPS Document with only one page of the original one. I tried to copy the document and delete pages from the copied document, but that's very slow. Is there a more efficient way to do this? In C# please.

Thanks.

Resolved:

```
public void Split(string originalDocument, string detinationDocument)
    {
        using (Package package = Package.Open(originalDocument, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (Package packageDest = Package.Open(detinationDocument))
            {
                string inMemoryPackageName = "memorystream://miXps.xps";
                 Uri packageUri = new Uri(inMemoryPackageName);
                 PackageStore.AddPackage(packageUri, package);
                XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Maximum, inMemoryPackageName);
                XpsDocument xpsDocumentDest = new XpsDocument(packageDest, CompressionOption.Normal, detinationDocument);
                var fixedDocumentSequence = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
                DocumentReference docReference = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence().References.First();
                FixedDocument doc = docReference.GetDocument(false);
                var content = doc.Pages[2];
                var fixedPage = content.GetPageRoot(false);
                var writter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocumentDest);
                writter.Write(fixedPage);
                xpsDocumentDest.Close();
                xpsDocument.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. [Open the XpsDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615021.aspx)
2. Create the destination XpsDocument (same method)
3. [Get the FixedDocumentSequece from the first XpsDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.xpsdocument.getfixeddocumentsequence.aspx)
4. [Get the first FixedDocument from the sequence.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015699/get-fixeddocuments-out-of-a-fixeddocumentsequence)
5. Get the first [PageContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.pagecontent.aspx) from the [Pages property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.fixeddocument.pages.aspx)
6. Get the FixedPage from the [Child property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.pagecontent.child.aspx) of the PageContent
7. [Get the XpsDocumentWriter from the second XpsDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.xpsdocument.createxpsdocumentwriter.aspx)
8. [Write the FixedPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604603.aspx)

Easy.

---

As noted by [Christopher Currens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721276/christopher-currens), it may be necessary to use `PageContent.GetPageRoot` instead of `Child` in step 6.

Comment: I was having trouble getting anything the FixedPage from the `Child` property of `PageContent` with several XPS files.  When the fixed page is set by the Source property, you need to use `PageContent.GetPageRoot` instead of `Child` for step 6.  It's in the MSDN documentation, but I kept overlooking it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, it can help a lot people looking for a workaround against limitation of Xps printing which ignores PrintTicket defined at page level.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/529120/printqueue-addjob-ignores-printtickets-in-xps-documents