# Split XPS document into multiple XPS documents

Tags: c#, split, xps

I'm trying to split an XPS document into other XPS documents. I've used the following code to get started which works fine for a single page but not more (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328596/extract-a-single-page-from-an-xps-document). In the code below I'm trying to extract the first 3 pages of the parent document into the child document. Once I'll figure this one out, I'll extract the remaining pages into other documents.

The problem I have is to add the parent's pages to the child, so I tried to create a copy of each page using a memorystream but I now get the following exception when calling the XpsDocumentWriter.

Exception: "I/O error occured".

How should I add the parent's pages to the child?

Resolved: this code works in my WF4 project.

```
public void Split(InputFile parent, string outputDirectory, int splitPageFrequency, CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        // Open the parent XPS package
        using (Package package = Package.Open(parent.InputFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string Pack = "pack://temp.xps";
            Uri packageUri = new Uri(Pack);
            PackageStore.AddPackage(packageUri, package);

            // Get the parent XPS document
            XpsDocument xpsDocumentParent = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Maximum, Pack);
            FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocumentSequenceParent = xpsDocumentParent.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
            DocumentReference documentReferenceParent = fixedDocumentSequenceParent.References.First();
            FixedDocument fixedDocumentParent = documentReferenceParent.GetDocument(false);

            for (int pageCounter = 0, fileCounter = 1; pageCounter < fixedDocumentParent.Pages.Count; pageCounter += splitPageFrequency, fileCounter++)
            {
                // Generate the child file name
                Guid documentId = Guid.NewGuid();
                string childName = outputDirectory + parent.InputFileId + "_" + fileCounter + "_" + documentId + ".xps";

                // Open the child XPS package
                using (Package packageDest = Package.Open(childName))
                {
                    // Create the child XPS document
                    XpsDocument xpsDocumentChild = new XpsDocument(packageDest, CompressionOption.Maximum, childName);
                    FixedDocument fixedDocumentChild = new FixedDocument();

                    // Add the parent's pages in range to the child
                    for (int pageCounterChild = pageCounter; pageCounterChild < pageCounter + splitPageFrequency; pageCounterChild++)
                    {
                        // Add the copied fixedpage to the child FixedDocument.
                        PageContent pageContentChild = new PageContent();
                        pageContentChild.Source = fixedDocumentParent.Pages[pageCounterChild].Source;
                        (pageContentChild as IUriContext).BaseUri = ((IUriContext)fixedDocumentParent.Pages[pageCounterChild]).BaseUri;
                        pageContentChild.GetPageRoot(false);
                        fixedDocumentChild.Pages.Add(pageContentChild);
                    }

                    //Write the child FixedDocument to the XPSdocument
                    XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocumentChild);
                    writer.Write(fixedDocumentChild);
                    xpsDocumentChild.Close();
                }

                // Set the OutArgument value
                NumberOfDocuments.Set(context, fileCounter);
            }

            PackageStore.RemovePackage(packageUri);
            xpsDocumentParent.Close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue by using the PageContent Source property when adding the parent pages to the child document. I also added loops to extract every n page to a different child.